# How to use property variables in if controller of jmeter

Tags: if-statement, testing, groovy, jmeter

[image]

jmeter is giving warning and not getting inside if controller

warning
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add double quotes to parameters so string concatenation will work

```
"${BASE_FILE_PATH}" + "/" + "${FHIR_VERSION}" + "...
```

Also see @DmitriT for better variable usage in scripts

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't inline [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) in Groovy scripts. Use [`vars` shorthand](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) instead.
2. Consider using [`file.separator` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) instead of slash so your expression could work on Windows

   ```
   ${__groovy(new File(vars.get('BASE_FILE_PATH') + System.getProperty('file.separator') + vars.get('FHIR_VERSION') + '/Post/indexForPost.csv').readLines().size() == vars.getIteration(),)}
   ```
3. Check out [6 Tips for JMeter If Controller Usage](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) for more details.